# pub.dev - my package not showing platforms correctly (web missing)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-pub, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I developed a flutter package **multi_image_picker_view**:
https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker_view

This package depends on `file_picker` and `flutter_reorderable_grid_view`, **they both support the Web**. But in my package, **web option is not visible** in pub.dev. Even this package **works fine on the web**.

*Help me to figure out why WEB is not showing on pub.dev.*

[image: pub.dev screenshot]

**My pubspec.yaml**

```
name: multi_image_picker_view
description: A complete widget that can easily pick multiple images from a device and display them in UI. Also picked image can be re-ordered and removed easily.
version: 0.0.6
homepage: https://github.com/shubham-gupta-16/multi_image_picker_view
repository: https://github.com/shubham-gupta-16/multi_image_picker_view
issue_tracker: https://github.com/shubham-gupta-16/multi_image_picker_view/issues

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_reorderable_grid_view: ^3.1.3
  file_picker: ^5.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/multi_image_picker_view/assets/close-48.png
```

‍**Commands I used to publish**

```
flutter pub publish
```

️**My Matchine Info**

- Flutter Version: 3.0.1
- Channel: Stable
- Dart Version: 2.17.1
- IDE: Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

**You can find the complete code Github:**
https://github.com/shubham-gupta-16/multi_image_picker_view

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [`lib/src/multi_image_picker_view.dart`](https://github.com/shubham-gupta-16/multi_image_picker_view/blob/49bfb7202eb9cd025332b1cc242d7e01d38108e2/lib/src/multi_image_picker_view.dart) depends on `dart:io`. `dart:io` is not available for the web.  Do you actually need it?  Skimming over the file, I don't see any places where it's obviously used.

Comment: `Line 235:`
child: !file.hasPath
                ? Image.memory(
                    file.bytes!,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                      return const Center(child: Text('No Preview'));
                    },
                  )
                : Image.file(
                    File(file.path!),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
          ),
```


@jamesdlin `File(file.path!)` is only called on mobile devices. It needs `dart.io`. How should I manage this.

Comment: You'll need to use [conditional imports](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#conditionally-importing-and-exporting-library-files) and refactor your code so that the web implementation does not use `dart:io` at all.  Or perhaps look into using [`package:cross_file`](https://pub.dev/packages/cross_file) and use `Image.memory` instead of `Image.file`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I saw the source_code of `file_picker`. It also uses `dart:io`. Then how it is available for the web and mine is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conditional import required

The reason why this package is not showing Web on `pub.dev` is that it uses `dart.io` without conditional import.

To fix this, I separated the file where it is used. One for web and one for non-web platforms. Then import them by using conditions based on the running platform.

**web_preview.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../image_file.dart';

class ImagePreview extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImageFile file;

  const ImagePreview({Key? key, required this.file}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      child: Image.memory(
        file.bytes!,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
          return const Center(child: Text('No Preview'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**non_web_preview.dart**

```
import 'dart:io'; // here I imported dart:io
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../image_file.dart';

class ImagePreview extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImageFile file;

  const ImagePreview({Key? key, required this.file}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      child: Image.file(
        File(file.path!), // Now I can use File class
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**my_package_file.dart**

```
...
import 'non_web_preview.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'web_preview.dart'; // conditional import

class MyPackageFile extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ImagePreview(file: imageFile); // Using ImagePreview class
  }
}
```